# Can kable read latex commands?

Tags: r, latex, kable

I have a table that contains cells with latex commands. For instance, one column header reads "\textit{Quantity}."

When I call kable on the table with the following code, the latex command (i.e., "\textit{Quantity}") appears in my document:

`knitr::kable(table, format="latex")`

When I change the format to "markdown", then the latex command gets interpreted (i.e., *Quantity* shows up in italics):

`knitr::kable(table, format="markdown")`

Is there any way to keep `format="latex"` but get the results of `format="markdown"`? I.e., I want the latex commands to be interpreted.

Comment: you need `escape = F` in kable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.
See the below example:

> data2$Physics<-c('$\frac{7}{20}$')
>
> Kable(data2$Physics)

Display the above inside kable , you will see latex equation displayed correctly.